# Writing query containing ORPC, OPCH and OPOR

Tags: sql, sapb1

This is a question already posted on [another forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/384214/writing-query-containing-orpc-opch-and-opor.html) but it has not yet recieved any answers.

I need to write a query containing the following on each line:

1. The DocNum of each ORPC, OPCH and OPOR,
2. The NumAtCard from OPCH
3. The DocTotal from OPCH / ORPC or from OPOR if OPCH does not yet exist.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Are you using SQL or HANA as the database?

Comment: I haven't yet tried anything as I'm not too advanced. I am running on SQL.

Comment: So what help do you need? Is it the SQL, or determining the relationships between tables, or both?

Comment: Yes, i cannot write the query myself as i do not know how to link the tables and pull the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.DocNum, 
b.NumAtCard,
b.DocTotal,
*

FROM OPOR a
LEFT JOIN OPCH b on a.DocEntry =b.DocEntry

LEFT JOIN ORPC c on b.DocEntry =c.DocEntry
```

*//Can you try this?*

Comment: Hi Audrey. Didn't seem to work. I did t exactly as you put it in, and it returned every field for three unrelated documents - one order, one invoice and some have a credit. I then removed the ", *" and that returned a number of an OPOR, then an unrelated OPCH then a price I couldn't figure where it was from?